# Disk configuration for server running IIS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I've inherited a website from an external company (who have gone bust) and I need to get it deployed to our servers (its 3 web sites running together)

However, in testing, although the app runs correctly, performance is poor and I am pretty certain this is because the app writes files to the local disk.  We only currently have a single disk in the server but as its virtual we can increase this to two fairly quickly.
Server is Windows 2008 running IIS7 and has two processors already.

Some of the files are 100mb+, but there are also lots of small writes and log file writes as well.

My question is where to put which parts of the application?
Is it best to have the OS on one disk, Web sites and files/log on another?
or sites and OS on one and files on another?
Is there a "standard" point to start from?

If anyone could reply with something like this, but with an explanation so I understand WHY!!
e.g.
C: OS
C: WebSites
D: Files
D: Logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background sounds like it's from Linux, because some people configure new servers taking the items you listed into account. We have a handful of IIS sites; we mostly run Apache and on Linux, so I'm taking a stab at this.

Where we have IIS, we also tend to have MS SQL Server. I would keep the Windows OS on a nice large partition, and put everything IIS, including the root directory on a second drive. IIS installs defaulted to C:\, but I believe you can move it to another drive. The names of the utilities and how to do this, are best left to those who do this regularly.

In other words, I'd make a gross disk split OS/IIS, and then tune from there. However, make sure you have lots of disk space and can defragment.

Comment: Basically I was "given" a box to deploy to which only had one disk in it and was pre-installed with IIS.  Fortunately SQLServer is on an entirely separate box already, so it's just OS/IIS/Files.